# AIX format descriptors for ps command on Solaris

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, solaris

Is there any way I could change the delimiter of the ps command output on Solaris?

On linux, I could easily use AIX format descriptors but I can't find anything similar for Solaris.

Comment: This is a better question for [unix.se] than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use option `-o`. Here is small extract from [page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/ps-1.html):

> -o format
>
> ```
> Prints information according to the format specification given in format. This is fully described in DISPLAY FORMATS. Multiple -o
> ```
>
> options can be specified; the format specification is interpreted as
> the space-character-separated concatenation of all the format
> option-arguments.
> It is not exactly like AIX, but you can tune the output.

For changing delimiter just use `sed` or `awk` command